# what happens to the memory allocated in functions?

Tags: c, function, memory

So I wonder what happens to the memory that is used in functions. I am writing a multi-threaded program and I wonder what happens if I just call a functions and its memory after it returns.

Comment: I don't really understand your question, can you please explain more?

Comment: Please be clear your question. Post your code and list the problem you have. So that we can able to help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation

Comment: http://nethack4.org/blog/memory.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Automatic" storage -- variables you declare directly rather than explicitly allocating from the heap -- is obtained from the stack, and essentially goes away when the function exits.

Anything you explicitly malloc() *MUST* eventually be explicitly free()d, once and only once. It's your responsibility to structure your code so that happens correctly. If you don't intend to use it after the function exits, you should free it before the function exits. If it's part of a larger data structure, or being returned to the caller, you need to design your program to be aware of this and clean up after itself when that block of memory is no longer needed.

If you allocate, you must free -- or must document clearly whose responsibility it is to free the memory when they're done with it.

(Note that this is very different from Java and other "garbage-collected" languages, where memory is automatically recovered when nobody is actively using it.)